# Accessing to files included in the app bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle

The following code works fine before iOS 8.
Now I am compiling for iOS 8 beta 5 I can not access to those files.

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
sprintf(appPath, "%s/%s/extfiles", [NSHomeDirectory() UTF8String],
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] displayNameAtPath:bundlePath] UTF8String]);
```

The result of app Path should be like:

```
appPath char *  "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/97726814-AA76-41AB-A9A7-296AAEF4F898/MyApplication.app/extfiles"   0x0054f44c
```

My application uses the files included in that folder to start so the result is that my app crashes upon reading the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code isn't right and should not work on any version of iOS as it makes no sense to concatenate the app bundle root and the *Home Directory*.  If it works then I assume that's just luck.

What you want is:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *extFilesURL = [[bundle resourceURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"extfiles"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this

```
NSString *str=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"extfiles"];
```

Hope it helps.